# Javascript Refactoring Assistance Needed

Tags: javascript, ide, editor

I've programmed this code (javascript countdown) and I have to put 141 of them on page. Doese anybody know if there is some way(program, script etc) that will do the following:
Change from `function cdtd1` to `function cdtd2` and `var sad1 = new Date();` to `var sad2 = new Date();` etc.

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
if(n == 1 || n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 4 || n == 5){
var timer1;
function cdtd1() {
    var sad1 = new Date();
    var dolazak1 = new Date(sad1.getFullYear(),sad1.getMonth(),sad1.getDate(),23,00,00);
    var timeDiff1 = dolazak1.getTime() - sad1.getTime();
    if (timeDiff1 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer1);
        $('#dani1Box').remove();
        $('#sati1Box').remove();
        $('#minute1Box').remove();
        $('#sekunde1Box').remove();


    }
    var sekunde1 = Math.floor(timeDiff1 / 1000);
    var minute1 = Math.floor(sekunde1 / 60);
    var sati1 = Math.floor(minute1 / 60);
    var dani1 = Math.floor(sati1 / 24);
    sati1 %= 24;
    minute1 %= 60;
    sekunde1 %= 60;

    $("#dani1Box").html(dani1);
    $("#sati1Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati1 + ':');
    $("#minute1Box").html(minute1 + ':');
    $("#sekunde1Box").html(sekunde1);

    timer1 = setTimeout(cdtd1, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd1();
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a javscript looping operation.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 141; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  // put code in here that has to run 141 times modifying the html target elements by using string concatenation
  $('#target' + i);  // This would be come #target1, #target2, #target3 etc up to 141
}
```

You ask specifically about the variable renaming which would not be necessary in this case since you are reusing the variable in each pass through the loop.

Since you are working with time information you may want to check out this Javascript library: http://momentjs.com/ and work through some of the information on this specific section: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: Thanks, but I have to modify more than one variable how can I do that?

Comment: What tutorials have you worked through to help you understand some of the basic concepts of looping, variables and program flow and execution?  I could rewrite your code and fix the problem you are having, but it wouldn't be much of an opportunity for you to learn.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp might be a good place to start. :-)

Comment: All tutorals I have read are from w3schools. I think that code should go like this:

for(var i = 1; i <= 141; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  $('#sad' + i);
  $('#cdtd' + i);...

But I don't understand how would this work for code because I want to have 140 countdowns on page and that mens I have to have 140 unique scripts, adn this will change existing script on page, and  have to generate new script. Maybe? lol I'm still learning :D

Comment: For performance reasons you only want one timer that updates the countdown values for all 140 items displayed.  Use window.setTimeout once to call a function that then loops through all 140 countdown timers and updates them appropriately.

Comment: lol I don't understand. Can you please give me some example code?

Answer (score 0):

[JetBrains Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) has great javascript refactoring features, including renaming of objects.